# Add external js file to footer with id

Tags: functions, theme-development, jquery, footer, plugin-json-api

I know how to add custom/external js but i dont know how to pass js **id** also.

i am using it as:

```
wp_register_script( 'validation', 'https://www.asd.in/script.php?id=3ff00a469474bbe71a9218a7f0377518', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'validation' );
```

but I need output in footer like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="3ff00a469474bbe71a9218a7f0377518" src="https://www.asd.in/script.php?id=3ff00a469474bbe71a9218a7f0377518"></script>
```

Note: ID **3ff00a469474bbe71a9218a7f0377518** most show in output

Comment: Can you please explain why  you need to pass JS id?

Comment: @Pratikbhatt this is a API and not working with ID, i don't know they are using it :(

Comment: solved by: child_theme_footer_script()

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `script_loader_tag` hook

```
function enqueue_validation_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'validation', 'https://www.asd.in/script.php?id=3ff00a469474bbe71a9218a7f0377518', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'validation' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_validation_script');

function add_id_to_validation_script( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'validation' === $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="text/javascript" id="3ff00a469474bbe71a9218a7f0377518" src="'.$src.'"></script>';
    }
    return $tag;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_id_to_validation_script', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Not working this and not showing anything.

Comment: you need to enqueue the scripts too...

Comment: i have solved by : child_theme_footer_script();